# Resigned and received a pay check

Tags: salary, resignation, human-resources

I resigned from my position from a company in December of last year and I received my paycheck (in January)  from the company that I resigned from. This past week I have phoned them numerous times and sent emails querying about over payment. As it is Thursday today I have not heard or received any communication from them

Can someone please advise me in what to do?

Comment: Are you sure the paycheck isn't for the work you did for them in December?

Comment: On 15th December I received my paycheck for December

Comment: I'd be very surprised if your employer paid you mid-month for the whole month's work

Comment: As it was Christmas holiday,  companies in South Africa usually pays their employees on the 15th of December

Comment: When I have resigned, I have received payments from the old employer afterward for a number of reasons. First, most employers pay in arrears, so the last check has come a few weeks later. Second, they've paid me for outstanding vacation time, again with a delay of a few weeks. Finally, I left a company early one January and I received my annual bonus for the previous year in March when they typically pay out. Your case may be different, but that's what telephones are for.

Comment: Just a 'regional' note for those of us in North-America - in South Africa it is not uncommon when paying monthly salaries that these will be paid a few days before the end of the month - being paid on or around the 25th is not unusual. That being said - being paid more than a week before the end of the month is a little odd.

Comment: FallenHero - while you were still employed at that company, when did you normally receive your salary? Does the timing of this payment seem unusual?

Comment: No the salary falls into place of when they usually pay out the salaries

Answer (score 6):

Many company pay in arrears, so the paycheck is probably the last of what you earned.

Basically, when you start working somewhere, if you get paid weekly, you get your first paycheck after your *second* week, which is a week late paying for the whole of your first work week. You then get paid every week, but every paycheck is delayed by a week, so when you leave you get paid after you leave for the time that you worked previously.

Check the paystub, it usually has dates for the time period that the check is for, separate from the date that the check was created.

Comment: The reason I am asking this question is that I have been calling since Monday 3 times a day and sent 3 or 4 emails and have not heard anything. As I am currently swamped at my new place of employment. I don't want to waste my time if they do not have the decency to give me a answer

Comment: If you're concerned that they'll ask for it or there are things that may crop up later, send a written letter to the head of HR (by name) via certified mail, requesting a return receipt of delivery and to whom. That way you'll have proof that you attempted to get answers if they allege that you should have done something and the check turns out to be a mistake.

Comment: Was it a physical check mailed to you? Or direct bank deposit? Checking the paystub will be the quickest way to tell if it was sent in error. if direct deposit, there is still a paystub, you just may have to log into the company's HR website, which you can still do because you have data there that you need to access.

Comment: It was a direct payment into my account. They payment website is an internal system only the head of finance can access

Comment: I recently had to get old tax information from a company I left last summer. I called HR, who were very slow to get back to me, but they just instructed me to access the employee HR payroll site that I used to use, and it had everything I needed. The paystub is yours, you have the right to access it, by receiving a physical or digital copy. Nothing to do except take the advice of the others and linked question in the meantime.